# "Fidi amanti" from Vivaldi's Dorilla in Tempe

Tags: classical-music, baroque, opera

The music of aria "Fidi amanti che costanti", in third act of Vivaldi's opera "Dorilla in Tempe", is not extant. A version of it, however, was performed in the [recent Naïve recording](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B076WTK9TJ), but with no clue about its provenance. Only on the very last page of the booklet one can find the following mention:

*Special thanks to Frédéric Delaméa for the reconstruction of the aria "Fidi amanti"*

I'm quite certain that Delaméa took the music from some aria of another Vivaldi opera to fit the new text, but I couldn't find which one. Does anybody know more? You can listen to this aria here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1nZhY5PF58

EDIT.

In his old recording (1994) Gilbert Bezzina also reconstructed that aria, using the music from "Or di Roma forti eroi" in Vivaldi's opera Farnace, but the result was not very satisfying and the new reconstruction by Delaméa is different.

Comment: In all occurrences of *reconstruction* I encountered, it was the score, not the text. (Texts were typically mass printed in the opera programme even in baroque, and have better chances of survival than manually copied score.) Are you sure, it was the __text__, which was reconstructed?

Comment: @guidot You are right and I meant just that: the text is given but the music is lost, so Delaméa took the music of some other aria, fitting that text. Probably I was not clear enough: I edited my question.

Comment: Delaméa is a well-known musicologist and specialist on Vivaldi. Maybe he can be contacted via the publisher of some of his work ? For example, specialist magazines  "L'Avant-Scène Opéra", or "Studi vivaldiani" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it, after listening to a lot of arias: the music is taken from "[Io son rea dell'onor mio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=un0wRouRORY)", in Vivaldi's Argippo. This aria was discovered only in 2006, so it was not known at the time of Bezzina's recording.